# Moving a Drupal installation to a subdirectory

Tags: 7, files, navigation, migrations

Ok, I've got a Drupal install with a lot of links inside various nodes. All of these links are relative.

The problem is that if they're going to say, an image or a pdf in the /sites/default/files directory, they stop working.

Let me give an example:

There is a link in a node like this:

```
/sites/default/files/image1.png
```

`www.livesite.com/sites/default/files/image1.png` works

`www.domain.com/devsite/sites/default/files/image1.png` does not work

How do I (easily) switch the links to work in such a way? Do I have to do an .htaccess edit, or is there something in the Drupal settings for this? This is for Drupal 7

Comment: This question has been addressed several time already here. Take a look at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10612/how-do-i-map-a-drupal-site-to-a-subdirectory-rather-than-root for a start.

Comment: The rest of the site works though, just not the files folder stuff.

Comment: You need to adjust how URLs are rewritten for those to work, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the module [Pathologic](https://drupal.org/project/PATHOLOGIC) that acts as a filter on your text formats (Full HTML, Filtered HTML) and basically rewrites URL's which are parts of fields depending the site configuration and Pathologic settings.

You can for example set **Processed URL format** to `Path relative to server root (/foo/bar)` and for the **All base paths for this site**, you fill in the different website URL's.